# is windows 8 metro style mode disabled on windows ten?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

On my windows 8 machine I can  open the hamburger menu and set chrome to relaunch with metro style ui. Is that no longer supported in windows 10? I can't see the option in the menu system.

**Edit**

For those who -1 this question, this is only because it is not useful, unclear or shows no research.

No research: How can I better research when the documentation for chrome still points to windows 8. Is there some documentation you can point to which would satisfy more research criteria?

Unclear: Obviously very clear. It can't be for this.

Not Useful: With more poeple using windows 8, I was surprised that this hadn't already been asked here. This was actually where I came to do the research, however I couldn't locate anything discussing this tagged under [windows-10] and [google-chomre]. Is there another method I should have used? I would expect this may be very useful to others with the same issue as me.

**Second Edit**
I would expect to find it in this menu as "relaunch in Windows 8"

Current view: http://prntscr.com/83u2k4

I've set tablet mode in the bottom left hand of the notifications menu in 10, still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Just turn "Tablet Mode" on in the "Action Centre" (speech balloon icon next to the clock, bottom right), and you get the full screen start menu, and full screen modern style apps

Comment: Not near the pc now, will check this evening, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 gives you the option for both the new style and a 'Tablet Mode' for full screen "Metro Apps" again and also gives you the full screen Start Menu again.